# 2ndQuadrant/Pglogical multi-master cluster installation

Tags: postgresql, pg-logical

I'm looking for a way to make a multi-master cluster with pglogical.

When I say multi-master, it's means 3 nodes, where each of them is a provider and a subscriber.

Currently I have two nodes that working fine as a provider and a subscriber at the same time.

But when I whant to add my third node, with the two others, the conflict_detections appears, because the subscription try to insert always the same tuples, like a loop.

So what I need in architecture for the cluster is :

- 3 nodes provider and subscriber as the same time
- 2 subscriptions for each node (to send and to receive data by a replication_set)
- 3 replication_set (to forward, all insert, update,delete orders on each node )

like this each node could send and receive data, normally.

My questions are :
Does anyone have already installed a multimaster cluster with pglogical ?
If yes, in wich order I have to do the subscription and the replication_set ?
Specially for don't have a conflict_detection, when synchronize data.
Does anyone could share me a example of installation step by step for the subscription/replication_set part ?

thank you by advance.

Comment: Good luck. This looks like a recipe for trouble.

Comment: Hello, maybe, but can you explain me how do it, if you already have installed it ?

Comment: I would never consider such an architecture. I would use a single master.

Comment: I see, my problem is that my manager would like a multimaster. he claim it is possible to have one with pglogical.

Comment: Try to talk him out of it. But perhaps someone has an answer, and everything works out...

Comment: Maybe, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this answer serves much purpose anymore given the age of the question, but someone might find this useful. It is indeed quite possible to do what you need. You have to essentially build what BDR does by hand.

First you create the three nodes:

```
pglogical.create_node(node_name := 'my-unique-name',
    dsn := 'host=example.com port=5432 dbname=testdb user=replicationuser password=supersecret');
```

Then create whatever tables and data you need. Or do this first, it's rather irrelevant. Once the nodes and database structure are ready, create the first replication set.

```
pglogical.replication_set_add_all_tables('default', ARRAY['public', 'whatever-else-you-need']);
```

Once that is done, set up the first subscription on the second and third nodes.

```
pglogical.create_subscription(subscription_name := 'sub1',
    provider_dsn := '<whatever you set up earlier for node 1>',
    synchronize_structure := true, -- this makes it easy to copy existing table structure
    forward_origins := '{}'); -- this is vital so you do not end up in an infinite replication loop
-- wait until it is done
pglogical.wait_for_subscription_sync_complete('sub1');
-- also set up replication sets here for the other direction
pglogical.replication_set_add_all_tables('default', ARRAY['public', 'whatever-else-you-need']);
```

Now you have one-way replication from node 1 to nodes 2 and 3. Next set up replication back from nodes 2 and 3 back to 1.

```
pglogical.create_subscription(subscription_name := 'sub2',
    provider_dsn := '<whatever you set up earlier for node 2/3>',
    synchronize_data := false, -- do not copy data, as it already exists on node 1
    forward_origins := '{}'); -- same as before
```

And finally set up replication between nodes 2 and 3, in both directions

```
pglogical.create_subscription(subscription_name := 'sub3',
    provider_dsn := '<whatever you set up earlier for node 2/3>',
    synchronize_data := false, -- do not copy data, as it already exists
    forward_origins := '{}'); -- same as before
```

That should be it. If everything went well, you will have six replications going between the nodes. You should have two replication slots on each node.

```
select * from pg_replication_slots;
```

As someone pointed out in the comments, multi-master is often a bad idea so do try to avoid it if possible. But if not, I hope the above helps.